# What is the trick in covering GE Lat/Long back to x,y?

Tags: php, excel, google-maps, kml, google-earth

There are there numerous historical threads talking about converting screen x,y to Lat Long and hypothetically in my excel sheet I can convert x,y and lat longs back and forth all day, but once I export the x,y as lat/longs into a KML file important into Google Earth the link is broken.  If I save the shape I just important, and run that back through my calculation process the x,y cords are so far off I can't relay on them for anything.

My process for making x,y is pretty basic:  Lat or Long = (x or y * delta + base lat/long)

The inverse is not as basic but doable: x or y = (lat or long / delta) - (base lat or lont / delta).

This works all day long in excel without any issues, but once Google Earth gets involved the resulting x,y pairs are so bad its not funny any longer.

What do I need to do to get GE exported lat longs to be more 'accurate' to what I expect the x,y pairs to be (or what they are in excel)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not accounting for the `cos(base_latitude)` factor in your delta-x formula.

One degree of latitude is the same distance everywhere, but one degree of longitude, measured at the equator, is a longer distance than one degree of longitude measured at 45 deg north.